# Represent expression in another basis

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Suppose there is a known analytic function $f(x)$.

Can we represent $f(t)$ in the form

$$f(0)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n\frac{(t+1/2)^{n}-(t-1/2)^{n}}{n!}$$

?

In other words, how to find the coefficients $a_n$?

Comment: Have you tried expanding out the $n$th powers in the sum, collecting all terms corresponding to $t^k$ for a fixed $k$, setting equal to the usual power series coefficient $b_k$, and seeing if you can solve the resulting system of equations for the $a_n$?

Comment: This looks more like solving $f(x)=g(x+1/2)-g(x-1/2)$ for $g$. Some sufficient conditions would come from "excluding periodic parts" and from "doing $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(x\pm n)$".